# SQLite delete row using rowid not working

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I created a sql query to delete a row given the rowid. When I run the query there are no errors, however, the row doesn't get deleted.

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + " rowid " + " = " + id;
db.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: If there are no rows with the given id then there will be no error and no rows will be deleted.

Comment: you can use this library to debug sqlite https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I used the vacuum function to regenerate the proper rowId. I was previously deleting rows where that rowId didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE rowid " + " = '" + id + "'";
db.execSQL(query);
```

But I personally prefer this way:

```
if (db.delete(TABLE_NAME, rowid+ " = ?", new String[]{id}) != 0) {
    Log.i("row", "Has been deleted");
} else{
    Log.i("row", "Has not been deleted");
}
```